# FEM for a 1D heat equation system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I want to know how to implement the (nonhomogeneous) initial boundary value problem for a heat equation;
$$u_{xx}=u_t ~~~x\in (-1,1),~t\in(0,1)$$
$$u(0,x)=u_0(x)$$
$$u(t,-1)=f(t), ~u_x(t,1)=0$$

Many text books only introduce the scheme $\frac{u^n(\mathbf x)-u^{n-1}(\mathbf x)}{k_n} - \left[ (1-\theta)\Delta u^{n-1}(\mathbf x) + \theta\Delta u^n(\mathbf x) \right] = 0$ for the homogeneous cases and it reperesents Crank Nicolson's when $\theta = 0.5$.

Could anybody give me a conscise example or a good reference for the above when the basis function is given by a (piecewise linear) 1D hat function?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is such a basic problem that basically everyone does in PDE classes. Do not get distracted if Crank-Nicholson is not showing up, the temporal integrator is not that important in the first place. You can start your journey by looking into [this](http://users.metu.edu.tr/csert/me582/ME582%20Ch%2002.pdf), [this](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Emohammad/teaching/PDEbok/draft_FEM_version6.pdf) or [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-33287-6_2), for instance. But there has to be plenty much more out there, also already pre-coded examples.